# Searching for tags within an object in a hashmap

Tags: java, android, arraylist, hashmap

I am trying to set up a search function where the user can search for a food item based on user input. The items in the HashMap are set up to have the UUID of a Food class object and the object itself.

This is the repository for the food items

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class FoodRepository {

    // Create a hash map
    private HashMap foods = new HashMap();

    // Constructor
    public FoodRepository () {

        //Food Objects
        NutritionFacts cokeNutritionFacts = new NutritionFacts(190, 0, 60, 54, 54, 0);
        String[] cokeTags = {"Drink", "Cola", "Coca-Cola"};
        Food coke = new Food("Coca-Cola", cokeNutritionFacts, cokeTags);
        foods.put(coke.getUUID(), coke);

        NutritionFacts drpepperNutritionFacts = new NutritionFacts(180, 0, 75, 48, 47, 0);
        String[] drpepperTags = {"Drink", "Cola", "Dr Pepper"};
        Food drpepper = new Food( "Dr Pepper", drpepperNutritionFacts, drpepperTags);
        foods.put(drpepper.getUUID(), drpepper);

        NutritionFacts cfaSandwichNutritionFacts = new NutritionFacts(440, 19, 1350, 40, 5, 28);
        String[] cfaSandwichTags = {"Entree", "Sandwich", "Dinner", "Lunch", "Chick Fil A"};
        Food cfaSandwich = new Food( "Chick Fil A Chicken Sandwich", cfaSandwichNutritionFacts, cfaSandwichTags);
        foods.put(cfaSandwich.getUUID(), cfaSandwich);

        NutritionFacts bigMacNutritionFacts = new NutritionFacts(540, 28, 940, 42, 9, 25);
        String[] bigMacTags = {"Entree", "Burger", "Dinner", "Lunch", "McDonalds"};
        Food bigMac = new Food( "McDonalds Big Mac", bigMacNutritionFacts, bigMacTags);
        foods.put(bigMac.getUUID(), cfaSandwich);

        // Get a set of the entries
        Set foodSet = foods.entrySet();
    }

    // Getter methods
    public HashMap getFoods() {
        return foods;
    }

    // Setter methods
    public void setFoods(HashMap foods) {
        this.foods = foods;
    }
}
```

This is the Food class which defines the objects going into the HashMap (getters and setters omitted)

```
public class Food {
    // Class variables
    private String uuid;
    private String name;
    private NutritionFacts nutritionFacts;
    private String[] tags;

    // Constructor
    public Food(String name, NutritionFacts nutritionFacts, String[] tags) {
        this.uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        this.name = name;
        this.nutritionFacts = nutritionFacts;
        this.tags = tags;
    }
}
```

And finally, this is the nutrition facts class

```
public class NutritionFacts {
    // Class Variables
    private int calories;
    private int fat;
    private int sodium;
    private int carbs;
    private int sugar;
    private int protein;

    //private int iron;
    //private int calcium;
    //private int vitaminA;
    //private int VitaminC;

    //Constructor
    public NutritionFacts(int calories, int fat, int sodium, int carbs, int sugar, int protein){
        this.calories = calories;
        this.fat = fat;
        this.sodium = sodium;
        this.carbs = carbs;
        this.sugar = sugar;
        this.protein = protein;
    }
}
```

A note, I'm sorry if this is too much; this is my partner and I's first time using android studio and we are both rather inexperienced with java.

We had been thinking something along these lines could work:

```
int caloriesConsumed = 0;
String searchValue = scan.nextString();
boolean flag = Arrays.asList(foods.get(key).tags).contains(searchValue);   if(flag == true) {
     caloriesConsumed = (caloriesConsumed + xxx;}
```

But the problem is that if the user is searching for the food using a tag like "burger" hoping for a big mac to show, that method requires the key to be known and in the code; thus, defeating the purpose of searching along the value.

Alternatively we have seen some people use methods like this:

```
String needle = "burger"
for(Map.Entry<String, Food> entry : foods.entrySet()) {
     Food v = entry.getValue();
     if(v.contains(needle))
          caloriesConsumed = (caloriesConsumed + xxx);
     }
```

but the .contains() method doesn't work for strings / isn't compatible since the HashMap's value is a special object and not a regular data type.

Thanks for any and all help, it is much appreciated!

Comment: Not directly an answer to your question, but from your problem description it sounds like you'd be better off with a hash map that associates keywords with lists of Foods rather than UUIDs with foods. That way, when someone asks for all the foods with keyword "burger" you can look that key up using HashMap's `get()` method and return the result rather than having to scan over everything in the map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last snippet could be a working solution.

```
if(v.contains(needle)){
    caloriesConsumed = (caloriesConsumed + xxx);
}
```

Here, v is a type of Food, so obviously it doesn’t have a contains method as you not implemented it.
As i see you will need to search in the v.tags field, but it is an array of Strings, which doesn’t have contains method. I would suggest to change the tags field’s type from String[] to List< String >, and then you can use tags.contains(needle) to look for the specified search item in tags.

**Edit:**
For the Map< String,Food> issue

In your code I see you use raw HashMap type

```
// Create a hash map
private HashMap foods = new HashMap();
```

The problem is, that in that way, noone knows that this is a String,Food hashmap, so obviously you will get error if you want to assign it to a String,Food entry.

I suggest using it like that:
    private Map< String, Food > foods = new HashMap<>();

Also change the getter setter to return/accept Map< String, Food>

Note: Using Interfaces instead of concrete types is a better approach in programming, but if you still want to specify that this is a HashMap (which i can’t see why you would, but lets assume) then declare your variable as HashMap< String,Food> foods

That should do the job :)

Comment: Yes, changing that Array to a List seems to have done the trick in letting the .contains method check it, Thanks!

Comment: ```// test
        int caloriesConsumed = 0;
        String searchValue = "burger";
        for(Map.Entry<String, Food> entry : foods.entrySet()) {
            Food v = entry.getValue();
            if(v.getTags().contains(searchValue))
                caloriesConsumed = (caloriesConsumed + v.getNutritionFacts().getCalories());
        }```
The problem I have been getting now is with the Map.Entry portion, android studio seems to think that this is the wrong types but I don't understand how it couldn't be String and Food for the types since that is what was put on the map.

Comment: Edited the answer